# Rspec controller test failing post #create with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a customer model that belongs to user, and my controller test for post#create succeeds. But I have a subscription model that belongs to both user and plan, and it is failing (I'm using rails 5.1.2).

Here's my spec:

```
#rspec/controllers/checkout/subscriptions_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Checkout::SubscriptionsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before do
      sign_in user
    end

    context 'with valid attributes' do
      it 'creates a new subscription' do
        expect { post :create, params: { subscription: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:subscription) } }.to change(Subscription, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Subscription controller:

```
# app/controllers/checkout/subscriptions_controller.rb

module Checkout
  class SubscriptionsController < Checkout::CheckoutController
    before_action :set_subscription, only: %i[edit update destroy]
    before_action :set_options

    def create
      @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
      @subscription.user_id = current_user.id

      if @subscription.valid?
        respond_to do |format|
          if @subscription.save
            # some code, excluded for brevity
          end
        end
      else
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @subscription.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    private

    def set_subscription
      @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_options
      @categories = Category.where(active: true)
      @plans = Plan.where(active: true)
    end

    def subscription_params
      params.require(:subscription).permit(:user_id, :plan_id, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :address_2, :city, :state, :postal_code, :email, :price)
    end
  end
end
```

Subscription model -

```
# app/models/subscription.rb

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :plan
  has_many :shipments

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :address, :city, :state, :postal_code, :plan_id, presence: true

  before_create :set_price
  before_update :set_price
  before_create :set_dates
  before_update :set_dates

  def set_dates
    # some code, excluded for brevity
  end

  def set_price
    # some code, excluded for brevity
  end
end
```

I'm also using some FactoryGirl factories for my models.

```
# spec/factories/subscriptions.rb

  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :subscription do
      first_name Faker::Name.first_name
      last_name Faker::Name.last_name
      address Faker::Address.street_address
      city Faker::Address.city
      state Faker::Address.state_abbr
      postal_code Faker::Address.zip
      plan
      user
    end
  end

# spec/factories/plans.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :plan do
    name 'Nine Month Plan'
    description 'Nine Month Plan description'
    price 225.00
    active true
    starts_on Date.new(2017, 9, 1)
    expires_on Date.new(2018, 5, 15)
    monthly_duration 9
    prep_days_required 5
    category
  end
end

# spec/factories/user.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name Faker::Name.name
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password 'Abcdef10'
  end
end
```

When I look at the log, I notice that user and plan aren't being populated when running the spec and creating the subscription, which must be why it's failing, since plan is required. But I can't figure out how to fix this. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is that a `Subscription` can only be created for a `User` and `Post` that **already exist**, right? So unless you want to change the controller to accept additional parameters for creating these associated objects, you'll need to make sue they are created **before sending the `post` request in the test**.

Comment: I'll write this up as an answer below, if my suspicions are correct from glancing at the code... It would be a bit of an effort me to fully recreate this locally :) ... basically, you just need to e.g. add `let!(:post) { create :post, user: user) }` within the spec context block.

Comment: For more detail, see also this discussion in the `FactoryGirl` project: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @TomLord, yes, a subscription can only be created after a user has been created. There's no post model involved here, though - I'm testing an HTTP Post in my controller spec. I'm creating the subscription in the example description: `expect { post :create, params: { subscription: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:subscription) } }.to change(Subscription, :count).by(1)`, but getting this failure: **expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that, by your model definition, you can only create a `Subscription` that is associated to an existing `Plan`:

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan

  validates :plan_id, presence: true
end
```

You could have debugged this issue by either setting a breakpoint in the `rspec` test and inspecting the `response.body`; or similarly instead by setting a breakpoint in `SubscriptionsController#create` and inspecting `@subscription.errors`. Either way, you should see the error that `plan_id` is not present (so therefore the `@subscription` did not save).

---

The issue stems from the fact that [`FactoryGirl#attributes_for` does not include associated model IDs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359). (This issue has actually [been](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/450) [raised](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/408) [*many*](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/316) [times](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/687) in the project, and discussed at length.)

You *could* just explicitly pass a `plan_id` in the request payload of your test, to make it pass:

```
it 'creates a new subscription' do
  expect do
    post(
      :create,
      params: {
        subscription: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:subscription).merge(post_id: 123)
      }
  end.to change(Subscription, :count).by(1)
end
```

However, this solution is somewhat arduous and error prone. A more generic alternative I would suggest is define the following spec helper method:

```
def build_attributes(*args)
  FactoryGirl.build(*args).attributes.delete_if do |k, v| 
    ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"].include?(k)
  end
end
```

This utilises the fact that `build(:subscription).attributes` *does* include foreign keys, as it references the associations.

You could then write the test as follows:

```
it 'creates a new subscription' do
  expect do
    post(
      :create,
      params: {
        subscription: build_attributes(:subscription)
      }
    )
  end.to change(Subscription, :count).by(1)
end
```

---

Note that this test is still slightly unrealistic, since the `Post` does not actually exist in the database! For now, this may be fine. But in the future, you may find that the `SubscriptionController#create` action actually needs to look up the associated `Post` as part of the logic.

In this case, you'd need to explicitly create the `Post` in your test:

```
let!(:post) { create :post }
let(:subscription) { build :subscription, post: post }
```

...And then send the `subscription.attributes` to the controller.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I had added let!(:plan) { FactoryGirl.create(:plan) }, and ... subscription.merge(plan: plan), changing it plan_id: plan.id did it.

Comment: Oh... Yeah sorry, I got mixed up between `post` and `plan` in my answer! Glad I could help you figure it out though.